# How to multiple point by float factor?

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning c#, and I don't understand how can I multiple Point by float factor.
For example, I have such point object:

```
System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(1, 1);
point = point * 2;  // error
```

What is the best way to multiple point by factor?

P.S. Should I use scale matrix for these purposes? (It seems too expensive)

Comment: You should use point.X and point.Y and multiple it.

Comment: But it is uncomfortable way. Maybe there is another solution? (except usage of scale matrix)

Comment: You can use Extension Method. Extend it and write your own method for multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is doing it as such:

```
point = new System.Windows.Point(point.X * scale, point.Y * scale);
```

But you mentioned in your comment "But it is uncomfortable way", so why not make an extension?

```
static class Extentions
{
    public static System.Windows.Point Scale(this System.Windows.Point point, float scale)
    {
        return new System.Windows.Point(point.X * scale, point.Y * scale);
    }
}
```

Then call the extention like this:

```
point = point.Scale(2f);
```

Just insert the `Extentions` class into your project code, then it should work.

**Edit:**

As a followup on x...'s comment. The line:

```
return new System.Windows.Point(point.X * scale, point.Y * scale);
```

can be exchanged with:

```
point.X *= scale;
point.T *= scale;
return point;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great point. But please, note that Point stores double, you have a cast to an int in your example, not so correct.
And there is nothing uncomfortable even with the first case btw, looks nice

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that `system.windows.point` is different from `system.drawing.point`. Thanks for `pointing` that out. And it was the asker who said it was uncomfortable.

Comment: Actually no need for "new", just return the same "Point", like the question above.